# Running a project with forked version of material-ui

Tags: material-ui

I want to start contributing to material-ui but before I submit a Pull Request I'd like to visually confirm that my changes have the desired effect. I followed the "install" page at material-ui.com and now I can run docs locally but I'm not sure what that does for me. I'd like to make a new barebones project that uses the material-ui that I have forked. Ideally it would use the material-ui that is on my local machine and not in my remote repo (this would allow me to make quick changes locally rather than having to push every time I want to see the consequences of a change). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npm link` to create a `material-ui` symbolic link inside `node_modules` that actually points to your forked version's physical folder.  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Example:

```
cd ~/projects/material-ui   # go into your forked directory
npm link                    # creates global link
cd ~/projects/my_project    # go into your project directory
npm link material-ui        # link-install the package
```