# Can I create a custom component library NPM package out of Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

Basically I want to

1. Have MaterialUI as the base package (@material-ui/core)
2. Customize all or the required components as per my branding and style guide and generate my own component library as NPM package. (customize @material-ui/core and create own package like @myorg/core)
3. Use those custom components in my project by installing the NPM package & importing. (npm install @myorg/core and import 'button' from '@myorg/core/button')

Because I want to create a common component library for different react applications.

[image]

Please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Did you manage to do this? Would you be able to share your approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can.

Creating a package is possible and even recommended if you want to reuse it in different applications or publish it.

Most of the packages are using another packages (called `dependencies`) and sometimes building new components on top of these packages' components. [You can read more about dependencies here.](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies).

Packages with `MIT License` allows `Modification` as well.

More information about creating `NodeJS` modules can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules).

And finally, if you are willing to publish the package in `NPM`, [follow this](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish).

Comment: Yes, I understand and have created packages of my own too but I do not know how can I customize an existing npm package and re-package it with a custom name and use them  as the dependencies. Hence an example would help.

Comment: [Maybe this will help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902029/running-a-project-with-forked-version-of-material-ui)

Comment: Thanks much for your comments, but I think that's not what I am looking for. May be I am not clear on my ask. I will see if can explain it properly to get the right solution.

Comment: Tried to create a graphic to explain my requirement. Also I was looking into https://bit.dev/mui-org/material-ui and here I see MUI components already in. But from here too what I would want is to customize styles according to my org. Let me know if that is clear?

Comment: Although I think you were clearer now, I still think that what you are looking for is forking the Material UI repository and changing the things you want. Then sharing your new package with others (or your org). [Read about forking a github repository here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo)

Comment: But I do not want to submit a pull request to the original mui repo and instead only will need to customize it and shared across different projects.

Comment: When you are forking the repository, you are not puling to the original repo... It is creating a copy of that repo that belongs to you.